# what is the use of SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a database by extending `SQLiteOpenHelper` class. And its created also. This is code I am pasting

```
public Imagehelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);

    cntxt = context;
    filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    DATABASE_FILE_PATH_EXTERNAL = filename.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+DATABASE_NAME;
    Log.i("Log", ":"+DATABASE_FILE_PATH_EXTERNAL);
}
```

Here everything is working fine.
    But if you focus on the parameters pass in super **super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);** . I am not able to understand the null parameter. I know here we have to pass the **SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory** object.

But how?? And what is the use of that??

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The reason of passing null is you want the standard `SQLiteCursor` behaviour. If you want to implement a `specialized Cursor` you can get it by by extending the `Cursor class`( this is for doing additional operations on the query results). And in these cases, you can use the `CursorFactory` class to return an instance of your Cursor implementation. Here is the document for that

[SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory DOC](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory.html)

> Used to allow returning sub-classes of Cursor when calling query.

Comment: Do you have an example of when you could want to do that?

Comment: There are any example ?

Comment: can you please provide any example of when we could want to do that? and maybe little snippet?

Comment: Is there any example?